# Does the `to` field of the 0xAPI swap/quote response always return the same Proxy Address

Tags: 0x

I'm working on a smart contract that uses 0xAPI data passed in by the user to execute a number of ERC20 swaps.

I noticed that the 'to' field of the `/swap/v1/quote` response seems to always contain the address of the [0xExchangeProxy](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff#code) contract.

So I was wondering if I could hardcode this address in the contract to avoid potential attack vectors resulting from calling arbitrary contract addresses passed by the user.

In other words are there any circumstances (for ERC20 Token Trades) under which the 0xAPI will return a `to` address other than above linked Proxy contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of ETH->WETH or WETH->ETH the `to` address is the WETH contract. This is a convenience with 0 added overhead of going through our contracts as a "trade".

The `to` address may change on different networks.

Currently for all "normal" trading the `to` address will be the 0x Exchange Proxy.